# How to pass values to another component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I am trying to get multiselect checkboxes in the dropdown.I am passing the list of values from app component to multi-selector-dropdown component. but i am getting error.

> Error in src/app/app.component.html (3:40)
> Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
> Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

How to resolve this error?

app.component.ts:

```
 import { Component, VERSION, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  list: any[];
  checkedList: any[];
  indi: {};
  constructor() {
    this.list = [
      { name: 'India', checked: false },
      { name: 'US', checked: false },
      { name: 'China', checked: false },
      { name: 'France', checked: false },
    ];
  }

  shareCheckedList(item: any[]) {
    console.log(item);
    this.checkedList = item;
  }
  shareIndividualCheckedList(item: {}) {
    console.log(item);
    this.indi = item;
  }
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rbrt5u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Share your html as well.

Comment: I have resolved this issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiselect-checkbox-dropdown-hrrsvf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: A suggestion - Not use 'any' at every place https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any